# Firebase's Realtime database's `child_removed` event not firing

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```js
let database = firebase.database(); //the database is empty.

database.ref('user').set({
    color: "red",
    height: 180,
});

database.ref('user/color').remove();

database.ref('user').on('child_added', e => {
    console.log(e.val());
});

database.ref('user').on('child_removed', e => {
    console.log(e.val());
});
```

I expect `'child_removed'` to fire because of: `database.ref('user/color').remove();` and I expect it to log out `'red'`.

`'child_added'` seems to work like so: it fires for every value `user` ends up with. So the only thing that gets logged to the console is `180`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you call `.remove()` before you setup the listener. Put your listener **before** calling `.remove()`:

```
let database = firebase.database(); //the database is empty.

database.ref('user').set({
    color: "red",
    height: 180,
});

// listener first
database.ref('user').on('child_removed', e => {
    console.log(e.val());
});

// then calls
database.ref('user/color').remove();
```

Comment: Why did the  'child_added' event successfully fire then? The listener was only setup **after** `set()` was called, too